# Bitbucket pipeline is failing and not letting me create the react build

Tags: reactjs, build, bitbucket-pipelines

since this morning I'm encountering an error in the build process of my React application using Bitbucket Pipelines. Nothing has changed to my application previosuly the same build was working but from today it is started showing the issue.

When I try to build my app locally I don't get any errors.

```
Build setup
6s
CI=false
<1s
cd React/WebApp
<1s
npm install
1m 57s
CI=false npm run build
6m 20s
+ CI=false npm run build
> dev2@0.1.0 build /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/React/WebApp
> react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.
src/App.jsx
  Line 50:5:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
src/common/card_information/card_information.jsx
  Line 23:7:    Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 23:7:    Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 23:7:    Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 27:7:    Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 27:7:    Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 27:7:    Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 28:9:    Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 28:9:    Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 31:13:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 36:9:    Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 36:9:    Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 38:7:    Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 38:7:    Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 38:7:    Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 60:17:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 60:17:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 61:19:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 63:17:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 63:17:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 64:19:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 76:17:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 76:17:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 77:19:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 79:17:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 79:17:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 80:19:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 89:11:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 113:13:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 114:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 114:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 114:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 114:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 114:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 115:17:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 117:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 117:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 117:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 117:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 117:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 118:17:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 118:17:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 119:17:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 119:17:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 121:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 121:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 121:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 121:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 121:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 131:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 131:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 131:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 131:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 131:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 135:23:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 135:23:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 136:25:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 138:23:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 138:23:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 139:25:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 145:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 145:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 145:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 145:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 145:15:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 149:23:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 149:23:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 150:25:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 152:23:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 152:23:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 153:25:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 161:19:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 185:7:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 188:13:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 195:11:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 197:9:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 197:9:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 198:11:  Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 201:9:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
  Line 201:9:   Missing "key" prop for element in array  react/jsx-key
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! dev2@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the dev2@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-02-25T13_22_41_074Z-debug.log
2022-02-25T13:22:41.098641374Z stdout P   Line 26:7:
```

I can add key on all the jsx but yesterday it was working with same code but now it is telling to add key props on all the jsx which is not possible because application has over 100 modules(I have removed error lines from error to keep the question short). even not all the jsx element it is mentioning is an array element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for this

```
 "react/jsx-key": 0,
```

add this in project's .eslintrc.json pipeline will start working

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same issue! Was some package updated to make this an error when it was previously a warning or something?

Comment: Found it!
https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/3215

Comment: Previously it was warning but from today it suddenly treated as issue @steezeburger